# What is the Qt way to obtain the intersection between two QLists?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, intersection, qlist

I have two `QList`s for which I need to determine the intersection (in this specific case, two `QStringList`s, but I would assume that this would apply to every container so long as `T` implements `operator==()`).

What is the Qt way to determine intersection between lists?

EDIT:

Order and duplication are not a concern.  I am just looking for the items that exist in both lists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Factors such as duplicate entires and ordering come into play if you're dealing with lists. If you just want to know which elements the two lists have in common you could do this:

```
QSet<QString> intersection = list1.toSet().intersect(list2.toSet());
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Chris.  Good to see you again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Updated for 2023 !

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QList <int> A,B,C;
    A << 10 << 20 << 30;
    B << 2 << 7 << 10;
    QSet<int> Aset(A.begin(), A.end());
    QSet<int> Bset(B.begin(), B.end());
    QSet<int> Cset;
    Cset=Aset.intersect(Bset);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Cset contains 10.... which is what I am looking for.

Hope this helps someone.